# Upload photo with jQuery Dialog in ASP.NET MVC site

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, upload

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC 3 application, and I'm trying to use a jQuery Dialog to upload a photo. Here is my code, but the problem is that the `HttpPostedFileBase` object of my `model` (witch represent the file to upload) is always null on the server side (`HttpPost` method).

**My controller**

```
public ActionResult AddProductPhoto(int id)
{
    var model = new UploadImageModel {ProductId = id};
    return PartialView("_UploadFile", model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddProductPhoto(UploadImageModel model)
{
    // model.File is always null
    return Json(new { Success = true });
}
```

**The model**

```
public class UploadImageModel
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [FileExtensions(Extensions = "jpg, jpeg, png")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

**The upload partial view (_UploadFile)**

```
@model DalilCompany.Models.UploadImageModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddProductPhoto", "Product", FormMethod.Post,
        new { id = "uploadProductPhotoForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProductId)

    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.File)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { type = "file" })
    </div>
}
```

**main view**

```
<span productId ="@Model.ProductId" id="add_product_photo_link">
    Upload photo
</span>
<div id="AddPhotoDlg" title="" style="display: none"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#AddPhotoDlg").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 550,
            height: 250,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Upload": function () {
                    $.post("/Product/AddProductPhoto",
                    $("#uploadProductPhotoForm").serialize(),
                    function () {
                        $("#AddPhotoDlg").dialog("close");
                        alert('upload success');
                    });
                    },
                "Close": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
            }
        });
    });

    $("#add_product_photo_link").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("productId");

        $("#AddPhotoDlg").html("")
            .dialog("option", "title", "Ajouter une photo")
            .load("/Product/AddProductPhoto/" + id,
                function () { $("#AddPhotoDlg").dialog("open"); });
    });                                         
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery), and I've decide to change my approch and use HTML5 to solve my problem. Thanks and good luck.

> With HTML5 you CAN make file uploads with Ajax and jQuery. Not only
>   that, you can do file validations (name, size, and MIME-type) or
>   handle the progress event with the HTML5 progress tag (or a div).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
$("#JqPostForm").submit(function(e){    
   e.preventDefault();  

    $.post("process_form.php", $("#JqPostForm").serialize(),
    function(data){
        if(data.email_check == 'invalid'){

                $("#message_post").html("<div class='errorMessage'>Sorry " + data.name + ", " + data.email + " is NOT a valid e-mail address. Try again.</div>");
        } else {
            $("#message_post").html("<div class='successMessage'>" + data.email + " is a valid e-mail address. Thank you, " + data.name + ".</div>");
            }
    }, "json");    
});});
```

I suggest you should use something like that to trigger form submit action

Comment: I dont need the submit form button, I'm handling it in the 'Upload' button (See the definition of the dialog). Other thing, by debuging, I hit the HttpPost method...

Answer (score -1):

You can't upload a file using $.post or Jquery's ajax as far as I know. So

```
$("#uploadProductPhotoForm").serialize()
```

doesn't serialize the file input.

What you can do in your submit function is:

get the file input using javascript:

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById("IdOfYourFileInput");
```

It will have a `files` property that contains the file selected files then you can upload it using `FormData` and `XMLHttpRequest`

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("NameOfTheInput", fileInput.files[0]);
form.append("NameOftheId", id);//this is your productId
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/Product/AddProductPhoto/", true):
xhr.send(form);
```