# Obtain <input type="file"> Contents In Ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, input-type-file

I want to validate a file being uploaded via Ajax before the user can submit it.  I make sure it is a .txt or .csv in javascript, then I want to call my controller to verify it matches our CSV standard.

I have :

```
 <input type="file" name="csvFile" id="csvFile" onchange="validateFile()"/>
```

and

```
function validateFile() {
    var file = document.getElementById("csvFile");
    var extension = file.value.split('.').pop();

    if (extension != "csv" && extension != "txt") {
        alert("A .csv or .txt file is required for upload");
        return false;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action( "ValidateCSV","UploadCSV")',
        type: "POST",
        data: { file: document.getElementById("csvFile") }, //unclear here

        success: function () {
            alert("success");
        },

        error: function (error) {
            alert("failed:" + error);
        }
    });
}
```

for the ajax data, how do i go about getting the `HttpPostedFileBase` that the controller wants from the file?  I was wanting to do all the validation before the user is allowed to submit it.  I'm not 100% that I'm 'allowed' to do this

Thankyou for any guidance

Comment: You can't upload a file via ajax. See [this answer for more information](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6462673/1199711).

Comment: Are you simply trying to verify that the file ends in .txt and .csv prior to submitting it for upload?

Comment: no.  the ajax controller does deep validation (verify headers, types, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to put the input in a form?

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">           
<input type="file" name="csvFile" id="csvFile" class="file" onchange="changeFile();validFile();" />
<div class="fakefile">
    <input id="csvFileFakeId" />
    <button onclick="return false;" class="blue">Browse</button>
</div>
<button type="submit">Upload</button>

</form>
```

Validate the file type, if invalid, clear the input and alert the user.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var fileId = "csvFile";
   var fakeFileId = "csvFileFakeId";

   function changeFile() {
       var value = $("#" + fileId).val().split('\\').pop();
        $("#" + fakeFileId).val(value);
    };

    function validateFile() {
        var file = document.getElementById("csvFile");
        var extension = file.value.split('.').pop();

        if (extension != "csv" && extension != "txt") {
            alert("A .csv or .txt file is required for upload");
            $('#csvFile').val('');
            $('#csvFileFakeId').val('');
            return false;
        }
    };
</script>
```

And when the post the form (this assumes the MVC endpoint is `Upload` or you have mapped that path

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer here using HTML5 file api. [Upload photo with jQuery Dialog in ASP.NET MVC site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325117/upload-photo-with-jquery-dialog-in-asp-net-mvc-site/18326409#18326409)

it was down voted but I always use it for uploading and it works.